# Python convert String to Tuple for REST API

Tags: python, api

I'm trying to build a REST API using django-piston and in the library, I can specify the fields to display using a tuples.

```
fields = ('id', 'title', ('author', 'username',),)
```

Hence, I would like to allow the developer to request the data format via GET operation such as:

```
http://localhost/api/users?attr=(id,title,(author,username,),)
```

I've read that I can use eval() to convert string to tuple. However, I met with two blockers.

1. Is there an easy way to add quotes to the param name such that it become "('id','title', ('author','username'))"?
2. Is eval safe to do it? I read that I can removed the builtin functions via this:  eval("('id','title',('author','username',),)", {'**_*builtins*_**':[]}, {})

For a little context as to why I'm allowing developer to specify the dataset, I'm following the advice from LinkedIn on how to build REST API.

Here's the link: http://blog.linkedin.com/2009/07/08/brandon-duncan-java-one-building-consistent-restful-apis-in-a-high-performance-environment/

Any help is really appreciated.

Cheers,
Mickey

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You didn't specify the Python version you are using, but here's a solution that works in Python 2.6 and doesn't use eval.

```
import ast

def parse_params(s):
    root = ast.parse(s)
    expr = root.body[0]
    return process_node(expr.value)

def process_node(node):
    if isinstance(node, ast.Tuple):
        return tuple(map(process_node, node.elts))
    elif isinstance(node, ast.Name):
        return node.id
    else:
        raise ValueError("unsupported node type %r" % node)
```

```
>>> parse_params('(id,title,(author,username,),)')
('id', 'title', ('author', 'username'))
```

Answer (score 1):

I would just use regular string methods for parsing, and whatever syntax you find suitable. In my opinion, it's totally uncool to expose your inner gears like that.

Comment: There is a huge benefits in allowing the dev to specify the dataset. In any case, this is an internal API used for mobile device.